# trollop output file with stdout as default

Tags: ruby, stdout

What's the best way to optionally specify an output file but use stdout by default?

Right now I'm trying:

```
opts = Trollop::options do
  opt :output, "Output File", :default => $stdout
  opt :input, "Input File", :default => $stdin
end
```

But when I try using it, I get:

```
$ ./test.rb -o temp.txt
Error: file or url for option '-o' cannot be opened: No such file or directory - temp.txt.
Try --help for help.
```

Obviously I don't want to require the output file to exist prior to running my script.

(Also, is the way I'm specifying the input okay?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code in trollop (specifically `parse_io_parameter`) I believe that currently, trollop (version 1.16.2) assumes any `IO` type argument (as in the question) is assumed to be for input.

The workaround is as follows.

Use a `String` to specify the output file in trollop:

```
opts = Trollop::options do
  opt :input, "Input File", :default => $stdin
  opt :output, "Output File", :default => "<stdout>"
end
```

Create an output object (`out`) based on the parsed argument:

```
out = if opts[:output] =~ /^<?stdout>?$/i
  $stdout
else
  fd = IO.sysopen(opts[:output], "w")
  a = IO.new(fd, "w")
end
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
out.puts("this text gets written to output")
```